# INITIAL_SIZE & AUTO_EXTEND in disk based mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I'm trying to create a disk based table which is documented in [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-disk-data-objects.html) link. However, it's not clear choosing the size of `INITIAL_SIZE` field in `LOG  FILE GROUP` and `TABLESPACE`. From the reading, I understand `LOG FILE GROUP` is necessary for transaction-based operations.
`INITIAL_SIZE` is used to define the commitlog size.

However, in `TABLESPACE`, if `INITIAL_SIZE` of `.dat` file is pre-defined, does that mean that mysql table can have maximum rows of `INITIAL_SIZE` Mb.

NOTE: There exists `AUTOEXTEND_SIZE` & `EXTEND_SIZE` in `CREATE TABLESPACE` syntax, However, it seems that they're currently ignored.

If so, how can I define dynamic sized disk tables on mysql cluster ?